# specify all major python version versions in gh-actions

Tags: python, github-actions

My gh-actions workflow usually look like

```yaml
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.6", "3.7", "3.8", "3.9"]
    steps:
    ...
```

Is there a way to specify all major Python version from a specific Python version onwards, e.g.,

```
python-version: "3.x >= 3.6"
```

without explicitly listing them as above?

Answer (score -1):

`python-version: '^3.6'`

> GitHub supports semantic versioning syntax
> -- [Source](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/building-and-testing-python#using-a-specific-python-version)

Comment: Is this really equivalent to `["3.6", "3.7", "3.8", "3.9"]`?

Comment: I think so… try it and find out!

Comment: Really? It’s copied direct from the docs. What error are you getting?